# OpenCV GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV and MPI to edit images (it is for a class) I am breaking the image into n pieces, each of which will be send to a core for processing, the image will be recombined later. So far I am trying to decompose and recompose the image and I get this error

```
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

many times then I see the first of n sections of the image and a lot of black squares popup.

My main loop consists of

```
image_descriptor id;    
                id.process_type = processingType;
                id.work_row_start = 0;
                id.work_row_stop = localcount[irank] - 1;
                id.cols = image.cols;
                id.rows = localcount[irank];
                imageCells[irank] = id;
                y += localcount[irank];

                std::vector<byte> img = matToBytes( image(cv::Rect(x, localstart[irank], image.cols, localcount[irank])) );

                cv::Mat reconImg = bytesToMat(img, image.cols, localcount[irank]);

                cout << reconImg.rows << "x" << reconImg.cols << endl;

                std::stringstream ss;

                ss << irank;

                cv::namedWindow("Original Image" + ss.str(), cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
                cv::imshow("Image" ,reconImg);
                cvWaitKey(1000);
```

Where for my image 720x601 `localstart` will be 0, 180, 360, 540 and `localstop` is that plus `localcount` which is always 180 (in this case).

If I simply use

```
image(cv::Rect(x, localstart[irank], image.cols, localcount[irank]))
```

my image is nicely split into 4 even sections, it is only when I try to convert it to a vector of bytes and back that the error comes up.

My conversion methods are as follows:

```
    std::vector<byte> matToBytes(cv::Mat image)
{
    int size = image.total() * image.elemSize();
    std::vector<byte> img_bytes(size);
    std::memcpy(img_bytes.data(),image.data,size * sizeof(byte));
    return img_bytes;
}

cv::Mat bytesToMat(vector<byte> bytes,int width,int height)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(height,width,CV_8UC3,bytes.data()).clone();
    return image;
}
```

With these changes to my conversion methods, my image is properly segmented and reconstructed, but I still get that weird error.

Comment: a ROI does NOT have consecutive memory, you can't just copy the bytes between datastart and dataend. if you have a ROI in matToBytes, you need to clone() that as well (deep copy) !

Comment: is there a proper way to put the data into the vector?